# Execute Stored Procedure against CMS from within a SQL Server Agent job

Tags: sql-server, query, t-sql, central-management-server

Is it possible to execute a stored procedure (or any T-SQL) against a Central Management Server (CMS) via a SQL Agent job?

The idea here is to exercise the CMS to hit all the registered instances with a query (or action), in an unattended (non-SSMS, non-real time) way.

Comment: Jason had suggested this type of action may be possible via PowerShell. Not using Powershell would be preferred, but being able to do this at all is even more preferred.

Comment: Might be on to something from an old K.Tripp blog post. In MSDB: sysmanagement_shared_registered_servers_internal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is: not possible, however my research lead me to these tables in MSDB which are used to populate the CMS registered servers. These tables can be referenced in your code:

sysmanagement_shared_registered_servers_internal

sysmanagement_shared_server_groups_internal